# Javafx: get a Scrollbar from a Treeview at a Button Event

Tags: javafx, treeview

I want to create a button event to create a list. On this list, the Scrollbar
should be moved. But I become an error because the lookup method is only usable after rendering.

```
HBox root = new HBox();
Button b = new Button("initList");
b.setOnAction(e->
{
    ListView<String> list = new ListView<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
    {
        list.getItems().add(i+"");
    }
    ScrollBar bar = (ScrollBar) list.lookup(".scroll-bar");
    bar.setValue(0.5);
    root.getChildren().add(list);
});
root.getChildren().add(b);
Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure to be called after the layout, you can queue the task using `runLater`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LookupTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox root = new HBox();
        Button b = new Button("initList");
        b.setOnAction(e ->
        {
            ListView<String> list = new ListView<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                list.getItems().add(i + "");
            }
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                ScrollBar bar = (ScrollBar) list.lookup(".scroll-bar");
                if (bar != null) bar.setValue(0.5);
            });
            root.getChildren().add(list);
        });
        root.getChildren().add(b);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }
}
```

Comment: If I do this then the Scrollbar is always null.

Comment: @jtp I made the code minimal working example. I cought the `ScrollBar` in this sample.